# What is the name of this puzzle?

Tags: wordplay, steganography, english

The English dictionary, as you may know, is a highly mutable entity.

While removing words such as [irregardless](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/irregardless) might be considered a good thing, others, such as
`snollygoster (n.): a shrewd, unprincipled person`
[are considered obsolete](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/snollygoster) and will be *missed,* at least by me.

Other words have actually *changed* due to constant misuse. The one that disappoints me most is the fact that ["literally" does not necessarily have to relate to its primary root definition:](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/misuse-of-literally)
`literal (adj.) in accordance with, involving, or being the primary or strict meaning of the word or words; not figurative or metaphorical`
It used to be fun to ask someone "Did you *literally* or *metaphorically* have your head in the toilet 'all night?'" *Now,* the correct answer might be "Both."

With this time-tested tradition of inventing new words and changing existing words "[willy nilly](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/willy-nilly)," I propose the following twelve *new* definitions of existing words.

Your goal is to

- determine the words being defined, and
- discover the word that *literally* (I swear!) presents itself as a moniker for this type of word (the name of this puzzle).

---

---

1. Uninspired mobile phone photograph (6)
   **_ _ _ _ _ _** ☑
2. Background checks on the key people in a company (8)
   **_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _** ☑
3. Adorable (condescending?) term for an inexperienced user of the World Wide Web (8)
   **_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _** ☑
4. An athletic protective cup (8)
   **_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _** ☑
5. Blog about electric, wrought, and farm items (9)
   **_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _** ☑
6. Spasmodic contraction caused by imprecise puzzle postings(8)
   **_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _** ☑
7. Marijuana prescribed for an STD* (9)
   **_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _** ☑
8. A Preggo's painful ped part (9)
   **_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _** ☑
9. Donation by a celebrity look-a-like "baby daddy" (9)
   **_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _** ☑
10. A trail to avoid in NYC's Central Park (10)
    **_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _** ☑
11. What I'm doing when someone throws poop at me** (9)
    **_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _** ☑
12. Discounted feminine product for everyone. (7)
    **_ _ _ _ _ _ _** ☑

---

*Possibly not technically an STD
**Happens more often than you'd think
☑ indicates a correct answer has been found

*Note: Please create a chatroom and offer invitations if you want to discuss the* **concept,** *as opposed to discussing the* **solution** *to the puzzle.*

***Hint Regarding Title:

> substr(0, 1) || substr(-1, 1)

Comment: [Sniglet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sniglet)?

Comment: @Phylyp I haven't thought about sniglets in a *long* time, but those aren't actual words... these are, just with new definitions.

Comment: This puzzle seems cromulent.

Comment: @IanMacDonald To be clear, each answer is 100%, forsurelike, actually in the dictionary. Each is listed as **one word**, even though I was not "totes" sure of this until I looked some of them up.

Comment: @Chowzen You may be surprised what you find in the dictionary. ;) http://www.dictionary.com/browse/cromulent

Comment: @IanMacDonald That's basically the gist of my opening diatribe.

Comment: [Obligatory clip regarding "literally"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TPLaMuHAr1U)

Comment: @MichaelK - Giving a YouTube reference before the [obligatory XKCD one](https://www.xkcd.com/725/)? Tut, tut 

Comment: @Phylyp Sorry, but Sorkin beats Randall (figuratively) in this round. I even say that Randall ends up third after [Weird Al](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Gv0H-vPoDc&feature=youtu.be&t=2m44s) as well.

Comment: Apparently "irregardless" made it into the list of [real words that people think are fake](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/there-is-no-such-word-as/irregardless).

Comment: This concept regularly appeared on the BBC Radio 4 programme "I'm Sorry, I Haven't Got A Clue", where they were called "new entries from the Uxbridge English Dictionary". Wikipedia lists them as "Daffynitions" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daffynition

Comment: So, then, all twelve of the words have been found. Now, I wonder if anyone is working on this: "What is the name of this puzzle?" A compilation of the correct answers (and explanations/clarifications) along with the correct puzzle name will get the **big ✓**.

Comment: The name of this puzzle is [ROT13](http://www.rot13.com/)("Jung vf gur anzr bs guvf chmmyr?").

Comment: I know; I only jest :P

Comment: DLosc's answer of "nutshell" to Q4 is miles funnier than the correct answer, but Chowsen has specifically replied 

“Perhaps, but *nutcase* as an answer would invalidate the ultimate question”

This is the biggest clue so far as to the overall answer.

Comment: Are the questions... (trying to ask in a way that doesn't tip my hand)... are they arranged in any specific order?

Comment: @jsm The Questions are in random order.

Comment: Does finding the final answer have something to do with the rot13(Crevbqvp Gnoyr) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, all the words have been discovered. [Another answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/65606/24910) already lists them all, so I won't repeat them. What is missing is the name of the puzzle. We have this clue:

> substr(0, 1) || substr(-1, 1)

which refers to a function used in some programming languages. Translated in English, it means:

> Take either the first character, or the last one.

So, what it means for us is that we have to take the list of all the answers and

> Choose, from each word, whether to take the first or the last letter (nitpicking: it could also mean that we have to take both, but it turns out that it is not the case).

We also know, from a comment that the OP left, that

> The Questions are in random order.

So, this is the list that we have to work on:

> M  C
>  C  E
>  N  G
>  T  D
>  F  T
>  P  C
>  C  S
>  A  Y
>  S  E
>  P  H
>  T  N
>  G  N

Now... I tried to figure it out, and some partial words that do fit are:

> mend, amend, def

Which I would combine into:

> Amendef (=Amend definition)

Which I find fitting, because it is formed in the way that this game works, and it even describes what it does! Unfortunately, this word doesn't exist. So, please bear with me if I say "amen" to that! ;-)

But this can't be the solution, because it doesn't use all the answers. So, I've written a program to try a brute-force with [all the 12-letters words that I've found](http://www.allscrabblewords.com/12-letter-words/), and the result is...

> Enchantments

For completeness, here is how it can be formed (there are actually 24 different ways to form it, assuming my program has no bugs, but I'll show just this one):

> Letter 'e' taken from pair 1 (ce)
>  Letter 'n' taken from pair 2 (ng)
>  Letter 'c' taken from pair 5 (pc)
>  Letter 'h' taken from pair 9 (ph)
>  Letter 'a' taken from pair 7 (ay)
>  Letter 'n' taken from pair 10 (tn)
>  Letter 't' taken from pair 3 (td)
>  Letter 'm' taken from pair 0 (mc)
>  Letter 'e' taken from pair 8 (se)
>  Letter 'n' taken from pair 11 (gn)
>  Letter 't' taken from pair 4 (ft)
>  Letter 's' taken from pair 6 (cs)

Comment: Well done and +1!

Comment: So you wrote a program that checked the letters against all of the words on that page? Kudos! Searching for a title, I put the 24 letters [here](http://www.hanginghyena.com/solvers_a/word-scramble-solver) in hopes of finding some set of words that could possibly be related and strung together. The one you found comes up first, right at the top, the only 12 letter word.

Comment: @Chowzen To be honest I was looking for some small program that I could write as exercise. So my main goal wasn't really solving your puzzle, but rather practicing some programming techniques. When I saw that, with all the clues, this puzzle could be solved with some coding, I decided to try it. And I'm glad I did!

Comment: I create and solve puzzles *often* as an exercise writing code and/or using RegEx, so my "Kudos" was certainly sincere.

Answer (score 14):

4. An athletic protective cup (8)

> [Nutshell](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nutshell)
>  nuts = testicles; shell = hard external covering
>  (Alternate definition, with a different split point: how it feels to get hit with a baseball while *not* wearing a cup >.<)

Comment: #4 LOL on both, but not what I was looking for...

Answer (score 9):

Correct Guesses:

7: Marijuana prescribed for an STD* (9)

> **Crabgrass** 
>  crabs (slang for an STD) + grass (slang for marijuana)

1: Uninspired mobile phone photograph (6)

> **Myo*pic***
>  
> 'myopic' meaning shortsighted / with poor vision + 'pic'

Wrong guesses:

8: A Preggo's painful ped part:  **Cornbread**

2: Background checks on the key people in a company:  **Big-screen**

New Guesses:

3: Adorable (condescending?) term for an inexperienced user of the World Wide Web (8)

> **Internet**
> 'intern' for 'non-professional user' + '-et' as a diminutive suffix

Comment: #7 works for me.

Comment: Great! Added another guess

Comment: More explanations would be great for non native English speakers

Comment: It's a "no-go" on Preggo.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your guess for #1?  I considered rot13('ovbcvp' naq 'zlbcvp'), but couldn't fit the prefixes with the clue.

Comment: rot13(V pbafvqrerq obgu nf jryy. V'z gnxvat zlbcvp gb zrna 'fubeg-fvtugrq' naq 'jvgu cbbe ivfvba' gb trg gb 'Havafcverq')  I'll add some explanation

Comment: #1 is just as you rot13'd. (correct)

Comment: @Chowzen I take this to mean I should keep working on #2?

Comment: Yes, sorry, #2 is currently not right. (☑ in original question shows that correct answer has been given)

Comment: Imaginative, but not it on #3

Answer (score 9):

1. Uninspired mobile phone photograph (6)

   > **myo*pic***     [from [TwoBitOperation](/a/65539)]
   >           (though I still think **une*pic*** fits 'uninspired' a little better hehe)
2. Background checks on the key people in a company (8)

   > **cor*vette***     [from [ManyPinkHats](/a/65595)]
3. Adorable (condescending?) term for an inexperienced user of the World Wide Web (8)

   > <s>Why is this not just **a*Dora*ble** for Dora the (Internet) Explorer?</s>
4. An athletic protective cup (8)

   > **nut*house*** — or maybe **nut*hatch***.
5. Blog about electric, wrought, and farm items (9)

   > **fence*post***     [from [hagfy](/a/65532)]
6. Spasmodic contraction caused by imprecise puzzle postings(8)

   > **pedan*tic***     [from [qwr](/a/65543)]
7. Marijuana prescribed for an STD (9)

   > **crab*grass***     [from [TwoBitOperation](/a/65539)]
8. A Preggo's painful ped part (9)

   > **arch*enemy*** — pregnant women often have aching arches from carrying Baby's weight
9. Donation by a celebrity look-a-like "baby daddy" (9)
10. A trail to avoid in NYC's Central Park (10)

    > **psycho*path***     [from [Squid1361](/a/65604)]
11. What I'm doing when someone throws poop at me (9)

    > **turducken** — ducken (ducking) the turd (poop)
12. Discounted feminine product for everyone. (7)

    > <s>**min*iPad*** — "min" (discounted) + "iPad" (for everyone) = mini-pad, a feminine product</s>

Comment: #8 Correct! --- #11 Correct!  --- #1 not

Comment: #3 Well, that would have been *very* sneaky of me, huh? **NO** :) ... #4 and #12: nice ones (ballgown!), but no. Methinks the prefix "ball" has struck out...

Comment: No house, no hatch, no nuts.

Comment: @Chowzen I protest. #4 and #12 are perfectly reasonable answers :) This is hurting my brain trying to think of anything better!

Comment: You're right, they *are* perfectly reasonable. Tell you what: I'll make a new puzzle *just for you* soon. :)

Answer (score 5):

Correct -

5 - Blog about electric, wrought, and farm items (9):

> Fencepost
> Blog post + electric, wrought, and farm fences

---

Additional guesses -

I got nothing...

---

Wrong:

2 - PRESSUPS

4 - BALLROOM,PITCHPOT

10 - SCREWDRIVE

11 - TWOTIMING (poop = #2, and you're timing the throw so you know when to duck)

Comment: Yes on #5! Good job.

Comment: #11 and #4 - Not what I had in mind, but LOL!

Comment: Well poo...I really liked 11.

Comment: Keep trying... Concentrate!!! You'll like it when it comes out (sry 4 the bad punning).

Comment: @Chowzen care to give more explanation on the clues? after seeing the correct answer for #5, still have no idea what this is

Comment: @thecoder16 The overall concept? For #5, for example, I've made a new definition of an existing dictionary word, "Fencepost." My *new* definition is also a noun: a blog (or tweet or comment, aka "post") concerning fences in general. Does that help at all? :(

Comment: @hagfy Your suffix for #8 might be a prefix in my word... and your suffix for #1 *is* the suffix for #1. Your 'definitely wrong' #11 explanation has touched upon its 'infix.' (funny: infix is a real word, yet Riley has given it a 'new' definition, just like the entire concept of this puzzle.)

Answer (score 5):

6

> Pedantic (imprecise -> pedantic + "tic") **OP Edit: *Pedant* -> one irritated by imprecision

Comment: #6 gets the "tick." (correct)

Answer (score 5):

3. Adorable (condescending?) term for an inexperienced user of the World Wide Web (8)

> Tatertot: 
>  Tater - potato computer (old or slow PC) 
>  Tot - small child

10. A trail to avoid in NYC's Central Park (10)

> Psychopath: 
>  Psycho - West side includes Metropolitan Center For Mental Health 
>  Path - trail

Comment: Cool, I was about to start hinting on this. Correct!

Comment: No [potatoes](https://i.imgur.com/0S5spVm.jpg) :)

Answer (score 4):

Guess for 2.

> CORVETTE = core (key people, possibly company=corp) + vet (background check)

Comment: That's it! #2 is solved.

Answer (score 4):

### Summary of correct answers, to help solve the naming meta-puzzle.

I've listed each correct answer, the meaning of the word, and why the pun works:

1. Uninspired mobile phone photograph (6)

> myopic - shortsighted
>  shortsighted / with poor vision + 'pic' [TwoBitOperation]

2. Background checks on the key people in a company (8)

> Corvette - sports car named after a small warship
>  core (key people, possibly company=corp) + vet (background check)  [ManyPinkHats]

3. Adorable (condescending?) term for an inexperienced user of the World Wide Web (8)

> Nettling - causing annoyance
>  
>  "net" (short for internet) + "-ling" or "-ler" (diminutive suffixes sometimes used to denote something small or cute) [Jason Horner]

4. An athletic protective cup (8)

> Toolshed - An outdoor shed for storing tools and other equipment
>  tool = appendage, shed = place to keep it [jsm]

5. Blog about electric, wrought, and farm items (9)

> Fencepost - A post which helps hold up a fence
>  Blog post + electric, wrought, and farm fences [hagfy]

6. Spasmodic contraction caused by imprecise puzzle postings(8)

> Pedantic - overly concerned with trivial points
>  Pedant = one irritated by imprecision +  "tic" [qwr]

7. Marijuana prescribed for an STD (9)

> Crabgrass - invasive tropical grass
>  crabs (slang for an STD) + grass (slang for marijuana) [TwoBitOperation]

8. A Preggo's painful ped part (9)

> Archenemy - a supreme and most powerful enemy
>  pregnant women often have aching arches from carrying Baby's weight [Rubio♦]

9. Donation by a celebrity look-a-like "baby daddy" (9)

> Supercede - to replace
>  supercede - celebrity = superstar -> super 
>  baby daddy = 'seed', which is a 'look-a-like' for cede = transfer, bequeath, or grant, hence it puns on 'donation'.
>  the 'seed' could also be a different type of 'donation' [jsm]

10. A trail to avoid in NYC's Central Park (10)

> Psychopath - a person with no moral conscience
>  Psycho - West side includes Metropolitan Center For Mental Health 
>  Path - trail

11. What I'm doing when someone throws poop at me (9)

> Turducken - a concoction of chicken, duck, turkey
> ducken (ducking) the turd (poop) [Rubio♦]

12. Discounted feminine product for everyone. (7)

> Groupon - group-buying website
>  Group (for everyone) Tampon (feminine product) [Kyle]

Comment: @ Chowzen - I've edited my to include every explanation you've endorsed as correct. But to my eye, the pattern isn't consistent. Can you confirm the *explanations* are correct?

Comment: I appreciate the inclusion of the explanations of how the clues fit the answers, but it is the answers themselves (or part(s) thereof) that are important. I was trying to come up with a title for the puzzle, did *something* using the answers (e.g. turducken), and immediately a word jumped out at me. I was so surprised that I decided to make it part of the puzzle.

Answer (score 4):

12.

> Groupon : 
>  Group (for everyone)
>  Tampon (feminine product)

New Guesses

4.

> thimbled
>  Thimble (a protective cup for fingers when sewing)
>  Fumbled (losing the ball in the athletic game of American Football)

Comment: #12 is another winner! Correct.

Comment: #4 is not what was intended.

Answer (score 3):

Is the answer to #3

> nettling or nettlers? "net" (short for internet) + "-ling" or "-ler" (diminutive suffixes sometimes used to denote something small or cute)

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling SE! If you don't mind, please take the https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour ! You'll also earn a badge. Would you mind explaining your answer?

Comment: #3 is correct! (rot13(qhpxyvatf, tbfyvatf, naq rttyvatf) are *adorable!*, Good show!

Comment: Note: I edited out the plural "s" to conform to the eight letter constraint.

Answer (score 3):

4. An athletic protective cup is a:

> toolshed 
> (being a place to keep an appendage)

Alternative suggestions that turned out to be wrong:

- trackpad

being a protective thing that would be used on a track?

- tentacle

tent referring to a covering, and tackle referring to both a sporting activity and the male appendage

Comment: Tent:no. Tackle:no. Appendage?Yes.

Comment: ... And I was about to answer "tacklebox"

Comment: I've edited to add a few more possibilities... but frankly, I still think DLosc's answer is so good, you should accept it as correct!

Comment: You got it! for disambiguation purposes, it was your answer that starts with T, has eight letters and could mean "An athletic protective cup."

Comment: :) rot13(gbbyfurq)

Comment: I see. You know, I still prefer “nutcase” :-)

Comment: Perhaps, but "nutcase" as an answer would invalidate the ultimate question (I wonder if anyone is working on this?): "What is the name of this puzzle?"

Comment: BTW, I'm out of votes for today, but I'll come back and upvote your answer (and others that I've been unable to vote for) in a few hours. +1

Answer (score 2):

12.

> Bicycle
>  "dis**count** = bi, feminine = cycle, for everyone because everybody can bike?

edit: thanks for the response! Been lurking for a little while, thought I finally had an answer to a riddle - looks like better luck next time.

Comment: Welcome to puzzling! That's not the intended answer, but it's a good try. Why not [take the tour](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour)? You get a badge for just looking. :)

Answer (score 2):

9: Donation by a celebrity look-a-like "baby daddy" (9)

> supercede 
>  celebrity = superstar -> super 
>  baby daddy = 'seed', which is a 'look-a-like' for cede 
>  cede also means transfer, bequeath, or grant, hence it puns on 'donation'.
>  the 'seed' could also be a different type of 'donation'

Comment: ...maybe a little explanation might help...

Comment: I've edited the answer with an explanation

Comment: #9 is correct. Thanks for expanding the answer for clarification to others.

Answer (score 1):

Partial:

3.

> webbings (or websters or maybe even webworms)

4.

> hardball (or ballyrag) <--- Original
> ballstop <--- New

Comment: #4 is incorrect because it's not *funny* enough. :) (Not that all of these answers are funny...)

Comment: Sorry, 3 and 4 are "out the door." (not right)

Answer (score 0):

Partial list:

1.

> Selfie

5.

> Metallica

6.

> Downvote

Comment: Your answer to #1 may be uninspired usually, but the intended answer is *certainly* uninspired.  #2 doesn't really work, because it is the normal, accepted word with that definition. The intended answer will "normally" mean something completely different. #6 see my comment on #2, plus, it's not really spasmodic.

Comment: I imagine that once some correct answers are found, the spirit of the intended answers will be better understood.

Comment: I think 1 is (rot 13)pnzren

Answer (score 0):

4. An athletic protective cup (8)

Wrong guesses, but still want to include them:

> **Frankenstein**
>  Frank -> weiner, another name for male genitalia
>  enstein -> in stein, or in a cup

and

> **Trophycase**
>  Trophy -> an athletic cup
>  case -> a way to protect it

Comment: You are CORRECT!  These are **not** conceivable as answers! (8 letters) Kinda funny, tho. :)