# Puzzling Solicitation

Tags: wordplay, knowledge

My 'copter's a Cooper and off I did zoom
To see [Rubio](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/65520/what-is-the-name-of-this-puzzle/65582#65582) in his nice, rubber room.

The question is:

> Where did I land?

On the _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ - _ _ _ _ _ _ _, of course!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Cooper is apparently a make of RC helicopter.
So of course you landed on

> the **nuthouse-minipad**.  Badum-tshhh.